# How to properly parse CSV file to 2d Array?

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a csv file into a 2d array, where each row is a data entry and each column is a field in that entry.

Doing this all at once simplifies and separates my processing code from my parsing code.

I tried to write a simple parser that used `String.Split` to separate file by commas.  This is a horrible approach as I have discovered.  It completely fails to parse any special cases like double quotes, line feeds, and other special chars.

What is the proper way to parse a CSV file into a 2d array as I have described?

Code samples in Java would be appreciated.
The array can be a dynamic list object or vector or something like that, it just has to be indexable with two indexers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/csv/)?

```
CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new FileReader(file));
String[] line;
while ((line = parser.getLine()) != null) {
     // process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file has fields with double quoted entries that contain separators and fields with line feeds, than I doubt that it is a real csv file... a proper csv file is something like this

```
1;John;Doe;engineer,manager
2;Bart;Foo;engineer,dilbert
```

while this is "something else":

```
1;John;Doe;"engineer;manager"
2;Bart;Foo;
   "engineer,dilbert"
```

And the first example is parseable with `String.split` on each line.

Comment: CSV files can be much more complicated.  Read this formal spec here: http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/csvSpecification.html and you'll see that newlines, double quotes and such are allowed within quotations